# How change value of element from great-great ... great-grandfather

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have panels which are dynamically generated and within each panel there is a table which are also dynamically generated.

By clicking the remove button, I would like to reduce the value of the `span.rows-counter, but only of its respective panel.

I currently reload the page completely for this operation, presenting the updated value, but I would like this experience better, simply lowering the counter.

[image]

Comment: how/where is the counter stored? How do you change it currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the target attribute to match the correct panel parent. Would look something like this:

```
$(".deleteItem").click(function(){
    let targetId = $(this).closest(".collapse").attr("id");
    let counter = $(".list-group-item[data-target='#"+ targetId +"']").find("#counter-" + targetId);
    counter.text(parseInt(counter.text()) - 1);
});
```

There's almost always a solution using some combo of these jquery functions:
 closest(); parent(); children(); next(); prev(); find();

Also, using more detailed class names will usually simplify the solution. For instance I would give the .list-group-item another class like .menu-item.

Comment: Ferpecto!!! It was exactly this syntax that was I trying to arrive. Worked like charm.